# How to pass tap event through WebView

Tags: xaml, webview, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I have a scenario in which
there is a GridView with zindex = 0
and
there is WebView with zindex = 1

If I make WebView beackground color transparent, I can see my GridView Items.
But they don't trigger click event.

Is there a way to pass tap event to GridView Items, while still having WebView on top of the Grid?

I have tried HitTestVisibility option, but not getting what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either have to use `WebViewBrush` which makes the rendered view non-interactive, but allows XAML elements to get input events or handle the taps in JavaScript inside of your `WebView` and pass them out through `ScriptNotify`.